# Update database in Controller with MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

On post from a form, I am receiving information via Ajax to my post actionresult in its complemented controller and implements this information into a table. This works fine, but I have this data and I want to UPDATE my other table with some of this data.

I have values for ArticleID, TimesRated and the Rating in my ArticleScore table. In my Article table I need to throw calculated data from this ArticleScore table into particular fields in my Article table, but where ArticleID = ID of the Article table.

I've searched for a couple of hours but can't find any resources on how to do this.
If you could help a desperate person in need that'd be great.

Cheers.

Here's my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewArticle(int articleID, int rate, int userID)
    {
        Article article = db.Articles
            .Include(i => i.AgeGroupToArticles.Select(a => a.AgeGroup))
            .Include(i => i.DisabilitiesToArticles.Select(a => a.Disabilities))
            .Include(i => i.StrategyTypeToArticles.Select(a => a.StrategyType))
            .Where(i => i.ID == articleID)
            .Single();


        try
        {
            db.ArticleScores.Add(new ArticleScore
            {
                ArticleID = articleID,
                UserID = userID,
                Voted = 1,
                ScoreValue = rate,
                ScoreCreated = DateTime.Now
            });
            db.SaveChanges();
            //Trying to hardcode this into Articles
            var allScores = db.Articles.Select(a => a.ArticleScores.Sum(b => b.ScoreValue)).First();
            var allVotes = db.Articles.Select(a => a.ArticleScores.Sum(b => b.Voted)).First();


            /*
            db.Articles.Add(new Article
            {
                ID = articleID,
                Score =  allScores / allVotes 
            });
            db.SaveChanges();*/
        }
```

Comment: can I see how the two models are built(Article and ArticleScore)?

Answer (score 0):

Your commented out code is trying to add a new article but it seems what you want to do is update the existing article (that you already retrieved from the db earlier).

```
article = allScores / allVotes;
db.SaveChanges();
```

If that isn't correct please post the exact behavior (including any error messages) that you are seeing.